# Rails Ancestry undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

I'm trying to learn how to use the "Ancestry" gem. I watched the related episode in Railscast and get the code. The `message` table works fine. But I'm trying to duplicate it with a new table called `locations`. I've copied and changed names on all the code (I believe).

I created the first location.  But, when I go to `localhost:3000/locations`, I get `undefined method`model_name' for NilClass:Class`for`_form.html.erb` line:

```
<%= form_for @location do |f| %>
```

`routes.rb`:

```
  Messenger::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :locations
    resources :messages
    root :to => 'messages#index'
  end
```

`_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for @location do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>
  <p>
  <%= f.label :locname, "New Location" %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :locname, :rows => 8 %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Post Location" %></p>
<% end %>
```

`index.html.erb`:

```
<% title "Locations" %>
<%= nested_locations @locations.arrange(:order => :created_at) %>
<%= render "form" %>
```

`locations_controller.rb`:

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @locations = Location.scoped
  @location = Location.new
end

def show
  @location = Location.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @location = Location.new(:parent_id => params[:parent_id])
end

def create
  @location = Location.new(params[:location])
  if @location.save
    redirect_to locations_url
  else
  render :new
  end
end

def destroy
  @location = Location.find(params[:id])
  @location.destroy
  redirect_to locations_url
end
```

end

`locations_helper.rb`:

```
 module LocationsHelper
  def nested_locations(locations)
    locations.map do |location, sub_locations|
      render(location) + content_tag(:div, nested_locations(sub_locations), :class => "nested_locations")
   end.join.html_safe
 end
end
```

Comment: You only have a `@locations` variable in your Index action, which is equal to `Location.scoped`. Your form_for is trying to use the `@location` variable, which should be equal to `Location.new` but you didnt declare it in your controller ;)

Comment: You could do something that could be discutable but useful: `form_for Location.new do |f|` (this means you don't have to create and share another `@variable` between controller & view)

Comment: OK - I changed the locations controller to have `class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @locations = Location.scoped
    @locations = Location.new
  end`  and still use `<%= form_for @location do |f| %>` - But, now I get undefined method arrange - on the index page